# Finding the Google Cloud project for a bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I need to help another team create a Service-Account for a GC bucket. The catch is that the maintainer uses a Google Group to maintain permission for this bucket. I've directed him to the Console only to find that the user who manages permissions has no projects associated with it.

1. How could this have been setup? (just curious).
2. How can I get him to be able to access the Console so a Service Account can be created?
3. Failing the above, what are some next steps that can be taken to track down what project could own a bucket?

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: 1. Whatever "gmail" account can be added by the owner with any role. 2. Someone with owner role could give the maintainer appropriate roles. Can you contact any user who manages permissions in the project in which you are interested? 3. What do you mean? All projects can own buckets.